# ContainerAwareCommand with get doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, cron, doctrine

I try use doctrine in cron job , i try follow some suggestion from stack and find to use

> ContainerAwareCommand

but seem have a problem with kernel , every time don't found him , here is my simple cron
namespace Site\Bundle\AdminBundle\Services\Cron;

```
class EuropatourCron extends \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure() {
        parent::configure();
        $this->setName("updateInfo")
                ->setDescription("Update db with offert from Europatours.at")
                ->addArgument('install');
    }

    protected function execute(\Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface $input, \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output) {
        $toDo = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('SiteAdminBundle:Europatoursofertacron')->findBy(array(
            'status' => 0
        ));

        $output->writeln(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($toDo));
    }
}
```

and here is my file from test:

```
// application.php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'src/Site/Bundle/AdminBundle/Services/Crons/EuropatourCron.php';
use Site\Bundle\AdminBundle\Services\Cron\EuropatourCron;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$application = new Application();
$application->add(new EuropatourCron);
$application->run();
```

i was try found a reson for this error but no found:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Console\Application::getKernel() in /var/www/europatur/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ContainerAwareCommand.php on line 42

Comment: Is this full stack or just using the console component?

Comment: i use php application.php updateInfo for run cron but give error

Comment: So you are not using the full Symfony Framework? If you are using the full stack Symfony Framework then you can just create a command and put it in a bundle inside a Command folder and Symfony will find it and insert the container (it will then be available through `app/console command:name`). If you are just using the components you will need to build the container yourself and inject it into the command.

Comment: please can you give a tutorial how to do that ?

Comment: Which? There are 2 options.

Comment: in my bunde i make a folder Command and was put there my cron.php and dosen't work that or i do someting wrong ( maiby need change somting somewhere) or dosen't work for me

Comment: There is a big tutorial about it in the docs - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html

Comment: thank you so mach this was problem , i forgot configure service in config.yml no local in my bandle , http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/commands_as_services.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create a file to run your command, you can ignore your `application.php` and simply run from the command line (within your project path)

```
php app/console updateInfo
```

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]            
  Command "updateInfo" is not defined.

Comment: Did you put your **EuropatourCron.php** inside a folder named **Command**? you should have your file as src/Site/Bundle/AdminBundle/Command/EuropatourCron.php

Comment: yes , i was tring and put there , change namespace but not work ... Site\Bundle\AdminBundle\Command but no...